# Chinese Idiom puzzle 17 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

A New puzzle for April 2021

[image]

1. Launch a direct attack on the enemy’s headquarters
2. Makes people happy and satisfied (especially when someone gets the deserved punishment)
3. Notorious
4. Extremely urgent
5. Give affection unilaterally regardless of whether the other party accepts it or not
6. One takes on the attributes of one's associates.
7. Cut ties (with someone)
8. Who doesn't make mistakes?
9. One hard work for permanent comfort
10. "Old and not die (是為賊也) "
11. Live groggy like in a drunk dream. Describes people who lack goals and live in confusion
12. A large number of customers of a bank withdraw their deposits simultaneously over concerns of the bank's solvency
13. Put onto a deadly ground; to kill
14. Leaves behind a glorious reputation forever
15. Energetic and ambitious
16. Something catches one's attention and makes his eyes bright up
17. Thousands of people have one heart. Describe unity
18. Easily obtainable
19. Extremely arrogant
20. Regurgitate other people's wise words
21. Appearance and demeanor
22. Childhood friends
23. Administer a country in the monarch's stead because the monarch is a minor or is absent or incapacitated

A. Leave repugnant reputation in history forever (opposite of #14)

B. Have ulterior motives

C. Escaped from a desperate situation

D. The emperor's mother sits behind a curtain and determined the state affairs.

E. The strategy of ally with the nearby states, and attack the faraway states

F. Live broadcast

G. Completely out of control

H. Capable people do a lot of works

I. Refers to rice wine (when you scold someone for drinking)

J. Making faces

K. Cantonese term for 'chatting'

L. Anxious for success, coveting immediate results and benefits

M. Worthless

N. The most famous advisor in the Three kingdoms period

O. Instrument

P. The four sufferings in life

Q. The model for all teachers forever (praise for 孔子)

R. Large scale fire

S. "Every person dies, my heart will shine through the history books" ( from a poem by 文天祥 )

T. Naturally die at a ripe old age

U. Deep maternal love

V. Like a lifetime ago

W. Clues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 直捣黄龙
2. 大快人心
3. 臭名远播
4. 急于(如)星火
5. 自作多情
6. 近朱者赤，近墨者黑
7. 绝交
8. 人谁无过
9. 一劳永逸
10. 老而不死
11. 醉生梦死
12. 挤兑(提)
13. 置诸死地
14. 留芳百世
15. 意气风发
16. 眼前一亮
17. 万众一心
18. 垂手可得
19. 不可一世
20. 拾人牙慧
21. 仪表
22. 青梅竹马
23. 摄政

A. 遗臭万年

B. 醉翁之意

C. 绝处逢生

D. 垂帘听政

E. 远攻近交

F. 直播

G. 一发不可收拾

H. 能者多劳

I. 黄汤

J. 挤眉弄眼

K. 打牙骹

L. 急功近利

M. 一无可取

N. 诸葛亮

O. 仪器

P. 生老病死

Q. 万世师表

R. 大火

S. 人生自古谁无死，留取丹心照汗青

T. 百年归*西*(**老**)

U. 舐犊情深

V. 恍如隔世

W. 蛛丝马迹

Comment: Good job, there are three mistakes. 4. 急如星火; 12. 挤提; T. 百年归老. You can Google them

Comment: @TangHo Thanks very much for the comment. Although 急于星火 is also an established phrase: https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%80%A5%E4%BA%8E%E6%98%9F%E7%81%AB

Comment: And 挤兑 is actually a synonym of 挤提：https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E6%93%A0%E6%8F%90#:~:text=%E6%8C%A4%E5%85%91%EF%BC%88%E9%A6%99%E6%B8%AF%E4%BD%9C%E6%93%A0%E6%8F%90%EF%BC%8C%E5%8F%B0%E6%B9%BE,%E5%AE%A3%E5%91%8A%E5%80%92%E9%96%89%E4%BB%A5%E5%8F%8A%E4%BF%A1%E7%94%A8%E7%A0%B4%E7%94%A2%E3%80%82